# Why does text-align: center work on videos?

Tags: html, css, video, center

So I was messing with CSS (just putting in random things for fun, even if I thought they wouldn't do anything) and I put `text-align: center;` on a `<div>` and it centered the `<video>` inside.
Can someone explain to me why this works?

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align. _"The text-align CSS property sets the horizontal alignment of a block element or table-cell box. "_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The  element is a replaced element — **its display value is inline by default**, but its default width and height in the viewport is defined by the video being embedded. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)</sup>

And `text-align` affect inline elements. The same for `img`, `canvas` and `iframe`

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense now.... though it still weird to me